# Change attr on scroll But return Default Attr When Scrolled Back To Top

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to change a URL for a image on scroll which i can do using this jQuery with a new image which is only displayed on scroll named scroll.png.

```
        $( '.div img' ).attr( 'src',"scroll.png" );

    } else {

        $( '.div img' ).attr( 'src',"no-scroll.png" );

    }
```

Works fine however, i need to remove it when i scroll back up which i can do using this :

```
$( '.div img' ).attr( 'src',"no-scroll.png" );
```

However, what i want to know is can i use another method to display the original image rather than add it back in the jQuery because its already added using PHP code so i don't want to ad it back using jQuery.

I was thinking something like this :

```
  $( '.div img' ).attr( 'src',"scroll.png" );

} else {

    $( '.div img' ).removeAttr( 'src',"no-scroll.png" );

}
```

But when i use removeAttr it removes the default image which is added using PHP code so maybe i need to use something like return.

**Update :** The default html includes a attribute for loading, maybe this can be used in the jQuery to return this image when the user scrolls back up?

```
<img src="scroll.png" loading="lazy">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is DOM changes which can't be achieved through PHP, client side needs javascript/jquery.

You can approach this in multiple ways through jquery.

1- Have 2 images, one has class/id noscroll and the other has scroll. Initially one of them is hidden(by adding display:none in style attr or .hide() in jquery) and the other is shown. When you scroll you switch their display value.

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="no-scroll.png" id="no-scroll">
    <img src="scroll.png" id="scroll" style="display: none">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    if(someScrollEvent){
        $('.div #scroll').show();
        $('.div #no-scroll').hide();
    } else {
        $('.div #scroll').hide();
        $('.div #no-scroll').show();
    }
</script>
```

2- Through PHP when loading the image and setting their src, set an extra attr say "initial-src" equals the initial src for the image, then when you change the src to no scroll and want the original src back you set it as the initial-src attr value.

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="no-scroll.png" initial-src="no-scroll.png">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    if(someScrollEvent){
        $('.div img').attr('src',"scroll.png");
    } else {
        $('.div img').attr('src',$('.div img').attr("initial-src"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. outputs 2 images in the HTML source which i don't like. 2. Is there anyway of doing this  without having to edit the default image which is added using PHP?

Comment: @Dev For point 2 you can reverse the condition 

`<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!someScrollEvent){
        $('.div img').attr('src',$('.div img').attr("initial-src"));
    } else {
        $('.div img').attr('src',"scroll.png");
    }
</script>`

Comment: I just want to restore the original image when the user scrolls back up without having to loading the image again. So i need a method which cancels the change of image URL not a method which adds the image back. that's the whole point of the question but thanks anyway.

Comment: I got your point and I pointed out that you can't do that, since the original image doesn't have "memory" of what it was before it got changed. If it were a background image you could achieve that by adding a class that replaces the background image and removing class to restore the initial image, but that's not your case.

Comment: Can't i just remove the new image when scroll back to top?

Comment: If you remove the image you'd have to create it again and insert it in the DOM if the user scrolls down again, which is worse that just showing and hiding it.